# Deleting an Original Column and Setting the First Row as a New Column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I have created three separate data frames from the original data frame using 'iloc.' Since each of these data frames contains the complete information for each year, I no longer require the original column, which pandas automatically labelled. Now, I want to remove this original column and make the entire first row a new column.  I know that using the **`drop()`** method is not the right approach, and I'm uncertain if it's even possible. How can I delete the original column and make the first row a new column?

```
yr_20=watch_nums.iloc[:,:8] #0-7
yr_21=watch_nums.iloc[:,8:16] #9-15
yr_22=watch_nums.iloc[:,17:25] #18-24
```

yr_20.head(5)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0K8G.png)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to directly solve the problem, but I found a workaround using 'pandas.rename()'. Since the column names were repeated at regular intervals, I renamed the original columns to match the values in the corresponding rows. Here's how I did it:

```
yr_20.rename(columns={'2020년':'표본수', '2020년.1':'1회', '2020년.2':'2회', '2020년.3':'3회','2020년.4':'4회 이상', '2020년.5':'관람 경험 없음', '2020년.6':'전체 평균', '2020년.7':'관람자 평균'}, inplace=True)
```

After renaming the columns, I removed the first row since it was now identical to the newly renamed columns. And of course, I had to repeat the process for the other two data frames.

Although it was a tedious task, I'm pleased to have completed it and can proceed to the next phase now.